# Android multi line EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a multiple line EditText and a submit button below it.
When the user taps on the EditText area, the soft keyboard appears.
It has an enter key on it, which enables the user to move to next line.
My problem is that the soft keyboard hides my submit button -
so that when the user finishes editing, he/she has to press the back button on the device to hide the soft keyboard to submit.
Is there any way to keep both enter and done button in the keyboard?
Or, is there some other better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use layout where the button stays always on bottom on page but on top of the keyboard,
something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_save"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/button_save" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_save"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        >

...all your stuff here
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `imeAction` in the xml layout which will allow you to call Done/Next/Search etc directly from the soft keyboard as long as your editText has a listener for those events.